# MapReduce MultipleOutputs Outputs Console Info

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I used MultopleOutputs in mine MapReduce progress to solve some problems,when it done,the console show that:

```
    File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=0
```

I want to get the real information about Bytes Read&Bytes Written,the how could I get the real infomation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you see on the screen after your job completetion is the list of all hadoop counters.

According to the [MultipleOutputs manual](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)

> MultipleOutputs supports counters, by default they are disable

So all you need to do is enable them back using

```
MultipleOutputs.setCountersEnabled(jobConf, true);
```